# Getting runtime error on submission for Kattis "Perket" problem. I am getting the right output locally, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python

I have struggled with the problem "Perket" from Kattis:
https://open.kattis.com/problems/perket

I succeed locally when i manually write the samples, getting the correct output. I get "runtime error" when i try to submit to Kattis though. Does any of you see the mistake? Is my program too slow for the requirements? Thank you very much and have a nice day.

```
import math

n = int(input())

ingredients = []

for i in range(n):
    new = [int(k) for k in input().split()]
    ingredients.append(new)

bitter = [val[0] for val in ingredients]
sour = [val[1] for val in ingredients]

diffs = []
for i in range(len(bitter)):
    for j in range(len(sour)):
        diff = abs(math.prod(bitter[i:j+1]) - sum(sour[i:j+1]))
        diffs.append(diff)
print(min(diffs))
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: I get "Run Time Error"

Comment: The full traceback one, not just that.

Comment: How can i see this traceback one? I am only given the "Run Time Error" and a cpu time of 0.07s. Failing on the first test

Comment: Run it, you will see a bunch of error lines.

Comment: When i run it locally with manually written sample data it works, the problem is when i submit to the website. Here i get error but no further specification of the error reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead, and did a lot of black-box bisecting to debug the issue.

It turns out the validation breaks (with a Run Time Error) on `math.prod`.

`math.prod` was introduced in Python 3.8, so the website is likely using an older version of Python 3. You should try and create your own version of `math.prod` (or find another way to solve the problem).

---

Found the Python version, from https://open.kattis.com/help/python3 :

> For Python 3, we use PyPy version Python 3.6.9 (7.3.1+dfsg-4, Apr 22 2020, 05:15:29) with the following flags: {files}.

For the record, CPython 3.6 has recently reached end of life (in December 2021). I'm not sure about the PyPy's version, but version 3.6 can't be downloaded from PyPy's website; only later versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I will avoid importing in the future if not strictly necessary, and i suspect that would be rarely

Comment: Kattis states they support all the standard library modules, so you can (and should) use them when practical (`itertools.product` & friends can be very helpful for these kind of problems). It's just the Python version that is an issue. But now you're aware of it.